# viper module without link on view

Tags: swift

I downloaded template for viper module and it has no link on view, how do I use navigation here?

Scene Delegate

```
let startModule = CardsCollectionRouter.createModule()
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: startModule)
        window?.rootViewController = navigationController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Router

```
class CardsCollectionRouter: PresenterToRouterCardsCollectionProtocol {
    
    // MARK: Static methods
    static func createModule() -> UIViewController {
        
        let viewController = CardsCollectionViewController()
        let presenter: ViewToPresenterCardsCollectionProtocol & InteractorToPresenterCardsCollectionProtocol = CardsCollectionPresenter()
        let networkService = NetworkService()
        
        viewController.presenter = presenter
        viewController.presenter?.router = CardsCollectionRouter()
        viewController.presenter?.view = viewController
        viewController.presenter?.interactor = CardsCollectionInteractor(networkService: networkService)
        viewController.presenter?.interactor?.presenter = presenter
        
        return viewController
    }
    
    func showDescription(description: CharacterModel?) {
        let descriptionVC = DescripModuleRouter.createModule(description: description)
        //How to go on next screen??
        let viewController = CardsCollectionViewController()
        viewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(descriptionVC, animated: true)
    }
    
    
}
```

may be I have an easy way to get a link to the view?

like view.goToAnotherScreen from router and I will have this method on my ViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to create navigation methods outside your router when using this pattern, as navigation is the router's responsibility. You can create `router.goToAnotherScreen` and call it from your view controller. When creating the router, you should pass the view controller to the router and inside your router you should call `viewController.navigationController?.push...`

```swift
class CardsCollectionRouter: PresenterToRouterCardsCollectionProtocol {
    
    // MARK: Dependencies
    private weak var viewController: UIViewController!

    // MARK: Initialization
    init(viewController: UIViewController) {
        self.viewController = viewController
    }

    // MARK: Static methods
    static func createModule() -> UIViewController {
        let viewController = CardsCollectionViewController()
        let presenter = CardsCollectionPresenter()
        let networkService = NetworkService()
        
        viewController.presenter = presenter
        viewController.presenter?.router = CardsCollectionRouter(viewController: viewController)
        viewController.presenter?.view = viewController
        viewController.presenter?.interactor = CardsCollectionInteractor(networkService: networkService)
        viewController.presenter?.interactor?.presenter = presenter
        
        return viewController
    }
    
    func showDescription(description: CharacterModel?) {
        let descriptionVC = DescripModuleRouter.createModule(description: description)
        //How to go on next screen: Use your VC instance, which is the one your VIPER scene is controlling
        self.viewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(descriptionVC, animated: true)
    }
    
    
}
```